# Has God appeared in human form in Genesis 18?

Tags: theology, vayera

As the title says, has God appeared in human form in Genesis 18?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you [edit] it to clarify? Specifically, to clarify where in the chapter you think God did such a thing and how you're reading that verse.

Answer (score 1):

The Jewish commentaries understand that God did not appear in any physical form to Abraham in [Bereishis 18:1](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/18.1#e0n7) (sources available in Hebrew and English at that link).

Ibn Ezra and others assume that God had already appeared in some vision, and only afterwards did the three angels appear as people.

Rashbam understands that the appearance of "God" was the three people, but he notes that the Torah often uses the name of God to refer to His angels, and thus, the appearance of God was simply that the angels appeared.

Bechor Shor understands that the "appearance" of God here was the vision/discussion that takes place later on, rather than earlier.

Edit: Traditional Orthodox Judaism strongly rejects any understanding that God has ever taken on any human (or other) form.